# Check if given date is between two days

Tags: python, date, datetime

For a private project I want to check in Python if one day is in a range of two dates. The tricky part is that I have to check it without the year.

The project is meant to calculate what star sign a specific person has and the year is not needed.

Example:

Aquarius 01-21 - 02-19 (21.01. - 19.02.)

All the tutorials I've seen are with the specific year but it seems too complicated for me to calculate that too.

I don't need the whole code, but a hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `day, month = 1, 2` `if (month == 1 and day >= 21) or (month == 2 and day <= 19): ...`

Comment: @deceze Post that as an answer and I will give you the credits for this. Tanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a reference year to the dates, just for sake of comparing it. The only tricky part would then be the range December - January. In those cases you would have to change the year to the next year.

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 21) 
end_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 19)
check_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 1)
if start_date < check_date and check_date < end_date: 
    print('success!')
```

Comment: FWIW, you can make that more concise as `start_date < check_date < end_date`.

Comment: As Zephyrus mentioned you can add any dummy year, but it can cause problems in Dec-Jan conversion, while comparing. From tutorials you have seen you can remove the year and can try.

Answer (score -1):

Use the datetime module of Python, it will handle the year part as well. Refer to the example code below. If anyone finds any mistake or has a better approach, please comment also.

```
import datetime

def datetime_format(date):
    date_list = date.split('-')
    date_list = list(map(int, date_list))
    date = datetime.date(date_list[0], date_list[1], date_list[2])
    return date


def compare_dates(first, last, date_):
    first = datetime_format(first)
    last = datetime_format(last)
    date_ = datetime_format(date_)

    if date_ <= last and date_ >= first:
        return("Within range")
    return("Out of range")


first = '2020-01-01'
last = '2022-12-31'
date_ = '2021-05-05'

print(compare_dates(first, last, date_))
```